# Get pictures from FireBase, some are well received and some are not well received

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Google's Firebase as a real-time database, and every time I get a picture, a picture comes up, and no picture comes up, so when I see the photo address in the internet address box, I see the following information. What did I do wrong? Did Firebase set it up wrong?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUpZ6.png)

The bottom is part of the code I implemented. This is the code I used to get the picture. I only used a few of the codes to summarize them. If it's hard to understand, please leave a comment. I'll fix it right away.

```
 database.getReference().child("posts").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            imageDTOs.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                PostInfo imageDTO = snapshot.getValue(PostInfo.class);
                imageDTOs.add(imageDTO);
            }
            boardRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return rootView;
```

below is my firebase DB Json File

```
"posts" : {
    "-M8l5cXJfuqfx-FskycY" : {
      "area" : "광교산",
      "createdAt" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 1,
        "hours" : 18,
        "minutes" : 15,
        "month" : 5,
        "seconds" : 25,
        "time" : 1591035325599,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 120
      },
      "location" : "서울",
      "photoUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/landmark-ce9b1.appspot.com/o/posts%2Fposts%2FpostImage.jpg?alt=media&token=c9e589f9-b00b-4bc0-8554-c65baef86f02",
      "postText" : "hello",
      "publisher" : "4dHDwEzOckOFcGiXZrYEAFBl9Xp1"
    },
    "-M8l5m3tCTnbL1Y2ng-j" : {
      "area" : "수원화성",
      "createdAt" : {
        "date" : 1,
        "day" : 1,
        "hours" : 18,
        "minutes" : 16,
        "month" : 5,
        "seconds" : 4,
        "time" : 1591035364676,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 120
      },
      "location" : "양평",
      "photoUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/landmark-ce9b1.appspot.com/o/posts%2Fposts%2FpostImage.jpg?alt=media&token=9e8f885e-dc7c-4262-865d-5e2ad5bde220",
      "postText" : "yhhh",
      "publisher" : "4dHDwEzOckOFcGiXZrYEAFBl9Xp1"
    },
    "-M8pL9rL9TXH56wU6fOA" : {
      "area" : "화홍문",
      "createdAt" : {
        "date" : 2,
        "day" : 2,
        "hours" : 14,
        "minutes" : 1,
        "month" : 5,
        "seconds" : 45,
        "time" : 1591106505881,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 120
      },
      "location" : "수원",
      "photoUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/landmark-ce9b1.appspot.com/o/postImage.jpg?alt=media&token=1587c3be-3da3-42c1-9afb-43178778a843",
      "postText" : "gigig",
      "publisher" : "4dHDwEzOckOFcGiXZrYEAFBl9Xp1"
    },
    "-M8qDa232fGlO4dU98xe" : {
      "createdAt" : {
        "date" : 2,
        "day" : 2,
        "hours" : 18,
        "minutes" : 8,
        "month" : 5,
        "seconds" : 17,
        "time" : 1591121297300,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 120
      },
      "location" : "수원",
      "photoUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/landmark-ce9b1.appspot.com/o/postImage.jpg?alt=media&token=20a18fea-7a88-4a89-b40e-793399b591a3",
      "postText" : "ㅇㅇㅇㅇㅇ",
      "publisher" : "4dHDwEzOckOFcGiXZrYEAFBl9Xp1"
    },
    "-M8uiVqORJP2z_vm4QB2" : {
      "area" : "장안문",
      "createdAt" : {
        "date" : 3,
        "day" : 3,
        "hours" : 15,
        "minutes" : 6,
        "month" : 5,
        "seconds" : 11,
        "time" : 1591196771190,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 120
      },
      "location" : "수원",
      "photoUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/landmark-ce9b1.appspot.com/o/postImage.jpg?alt=media&token=a29313ab-bf27-4222-aed2-8e1a9d186900",
      "postText" : "장장안안문문",
      "publisher" : "4dHDwEzOckOFcGiXZrYEAFBl9Xp1"
    },
    "-M8unttxYiTyPHIZ3r-R" : {
      "area" : "장안문",
      "createdAt" : {
        "date" : 3,
        "day" : 3,
        "hours" : 15,
        "minutes" : 29,
        "month" : 5,
        "seconds" : 44,
        "time" : 1591198184993,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 120
      },
      "location" : "수원",
      "photoUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/landmark-ce9b1.appspot.com/o/postImage.jpg?alt=media&token=69bc1377-8d1a-47ea-aa8c-d86126033bda",
      "postText" : "장안",
      "publisher" : "4dHDwEzOckOFcGiXZrYEAFBl9Xp1"
    },
    "-M8uo52uiNPHHWl74uWU" : {
      "area" : "장안문",
      "createdAt" : {
        "date" : 3,
        "day" : 3,
        "hours" : 15,
        "minutes" : 30,
        "month" : 5,
        "seconds" : 34,
        "time" : 1591198234782,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 120
      },
      "location" : "수원",
      "photoUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/landmark-ce9b1.appspot.com/o/postImage.jpg?alt=media&token=8d011a38-8cf4-4461-bd51-9e1e8777cd1f",
      "postText" : "장안문",
      "publisher" : "4dHDwEzOckOFcGiXZrYEAFBl9Xp1"
    },
    "-M8uoA0MgVzuPhkFqEhP" : {
      "area" : "장안문",
      "createdAt" : {
        "date" : 3,
        "day" : 3,
        "hours" : 15,
        "minutes" : 30,
        "month" : 5,
        "seconds" : 55,
        "time" : 1591198255099,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 120
      },
      "location" : "수원",
      "photoUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/landmark-ce9b1.appspot.com/o/postImage.jpg?alt=media&token=f61427c3-b038-4e80-b19a-393c582e5db1",
      "postText" : "장안",
      "publisher" : "4dHDwEzOckOFcGiXZrYEAFBl9Xp1"
    },
    "-M8y8Xe2rWUOpLR0tWnL" : {
      "area" : "빙화수류정",
      "createdAt" : {
        "date" : 4,
        "day" : 4,
        "hours" : 16,
        "minutes" : 5,
        "month" : 5,
        "seconds" : 28,
        "time" : 1591254328625,
        "timezoneOffset" : -540,
        "year" : 120
      },
      "location" : "수원",
      "photoUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/landmark-ce9b1.appspot.com/o/postImage.jpg?alt=media&token=69321055-833d-40d9-8073-089a351e9c17",
      "postText" : "정말좋아요",
      "publisher" : "yUkpoOxf3dTDaV4GnUslHubQI7I2"
    },
    "-M9-PVpvbpl-1LG2H4bt" : {
      "area" : "아주대학교",
      "createdAt" : {
        "date" : 4,
        "day" : 4,
        "hours" : 17,
        "minutes" : 36,
        "month" : 5,
        "seconds" : 29,
        "time" : 1591292189610,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 120
      },
      "location" : "수원",
      "photoUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/landmark-ce9b1.appspot.com/o/postImage.jpg?alt=media&token=92d831be-db33-4e1e-8506-81ab9847d1b9",
      "postText" : "아주대",
      "publisher" : "QJBqAoLgFTQpvxerjPWY1MhVXSk1"
    },
    "-M9-PaNJs91mhxGvKTbO" : {
      "area" : "아주대학교",
      "createdAt" : {
        "date" : 4,
        "day" : 4,
        "hours" : 17,
        "minutes" : 36,
        "month" : 5,
        "seconds" : 52,
        "time" : 1591292212291,
        "timezoneOffset" : 0,
        "year" : 120
      },
      "location" : "수원",
      "photoUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/landmark-ce9b1.appspot.com/o/postImage.jpg?alt=media&token=2148b536-d9c3-4729-af2c-9a80a4c34be5",
      "postText" : "아주대학",
      "publisher" : "QJBqAoLgFTQpvxerjPWY1MhVXSk1"
    }
  }
```

also below is my PostInfo class

```
public class PostInfo {
    private String postText;
    private String photoUrl;
    private String publisher;
    private String location;
    private String area;
    @ServerTimestamp
    private Date createdAt;

    public PostInfo(){
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class)
    }
    public PostInfo(String postText, String photoUrl, String publisher, String location, String area) {
        this.postText = postText;
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.location = location;
        this.area = area;
    }

    public PostInfo(String postText, String photoUrl, String publisher, String location, String area, Date createdAt) {
        this.postText = postText;
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.location = location;
        this.area = area;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getPhotoUrl(){
        return this.photoUrl;
    }
    public String getPostText() { return this.postText; }
    public String getArea() { return this.area; }

    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("postText", postText);
        result.put("photoUrl", photoUrl);
        result.put("publisher", publisher);
        result.put("location", location);
        result.put("area", area);
        result.put("createdAt", createdAt);
        return result;
    }

    public void setPostText(String postText) {
        this.postText = postText;
    }

    public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl) {
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public void setArea(String area) {
        this.area = area;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }
}
```

The details are as follows.[Feed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt6iC.png)

Comment: Can you show the JSON that is in your database under `posts` (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Is this right that you want?

Comment: Please edit your question and also add the content of your `PostInfo` class.

Comment: @AlexMamo Is this right that you want?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct security rules set?

Comment: @AlexMamo I can't understand what you said. What's the meaning about security rules set? Can I set it up in Java file or Firebase?

Comment: In the Firebase console.

Comment: @AlexMamo How do I know if it's properly set up? Of course, I  allowed Google Authentication, and I set SHA-1 and SHA-256 and then I got the goodservice.json file. The only thing that bothers me a little bit is, when I first started the project, I didn't set SHA-1 and SHA_256 so I set it up later.

Comment: I'm talking about storage rules.

Comment: @AlexMamo In my project, I don't use Storage. What I use is Database, so I didn't set anything up for Storage.

Comment: If you're talking about setting up a database, this is what I did.
{
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

Comment: You are indeed using the Storage. `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/landmark-ce9b1.appspot.com/o/posts%2Fposts%2FpostImage.jpg?alt=media&token=c9e589f9-b00b-4bc0-8554-c65baef86f02` is a storage link

Comment: @AlexMamo When I went to the link you told me, it came up like this.
Will enabling Storage solve this problem?
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
  }
}

Comment: I posted a picture of feed on the last line of the body of the question, so please refer to it. Thank you

Comment: @AlexMamo I changed the storage authority, and it's working pretty well. Thank you.